# Skip an element from Enumeration Java

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I want to skip a certain request parameter using Enumeration. I use the below code but it didn't give me the desired result. Can any one tell how would I skip an element from Enumeration or whats wrong with the below code?

```
 for (Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        if("James".equalsIgnoreCase(e.nextElement().toString())) {
            e.nextElement();
            continue;
        } else {
            list.add(e.nextElement().toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `nextElement()` multiple times per loop skipping multiple elements. You need to only call `nextElement()` once. Something like...

```
for (Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    String value = e.nextElement();
    if(!"James".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
        list.add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, you are invoking `e.nextElement()` two times in your `if`. That will consume two elements.

You should store the element in a String type first, and then do the comparison: -

```
for (Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    String elem = e.nextElement();
    if("James".equalsIgnoreCase(elem)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        list.add(elem);
    }
}
```

And you don't need that `toString()` after `e.nextElement()`. It will give you `String` only, as you are using generic type.

---

As a side note, I would prefer to use a `while` loop in this case, as number of iteration is not fixed. Below is the equivalent `while` loop version for your `for-loop`: -

```
{
    Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames();

    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String elem = e.nextElement();
        if(!"James".equalsIgnoreCase(elem)) {
            list.add(elem);
        } 
    }

}
```